# I am getting an error some times when uploading themes

Tags: errors

I am getting an error message When uploading some themes .

```
Warning: fopen(/home/..../public_html/...../wp-content/themes/creativeart/style.css) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/...../public_html/...../wp-includes/functions.php on line 4165

Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/...../public_html/...../wp-includes/functions.php on line 4168

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/...../public_html/...../wp-includes/functions.php on line 4171
```

What does it mean ?I don't understand if the problem in themes or Am I missing some thing in my Wordpress Installation? I have tried the same themes in two wordpress installations and  got the same error .

I am listing some of themes here .

[mysticgrunge](http://www.freethemelayouts.com/dls/mysticgrunge.zip/211)

[creativeart](http://www.freethemelayouts.com/dls/creativeart.zip/163)

Does any one have idea on such error?

Comment: The problem was with the themes I tried .It is ok with other themes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of things, it's a server issue.  The WordPress theme uploader uses `fopen()` to transfer files from one location to the server.  It looks like there's a timeout or access error because a) `fopen` can't find the file that it's supposed to be transferring and b) the `fread` and `fclose` functions can't find the data stream to read the file and close it.

I would recommend manually uploading the themes instead to bypass this error.  Instead of uploading the `.zip` file via WordPress, do the following:

1. Unzip the theme folder somewhere on your local machine
2. Log in to your site's FTP system
3. Navigate to `/wp-content/themes/`
4. Use FTP to transfer the entire theme folder from your local machine to the server

This will entirely bypass any kind of `fopen`/`fread`/`fclose` errors you're getting.  If there's still a problem, then it's an issue with either your server, your WordPress installation itself, or the actual theme and will require some more in-depth troubleshooting.

Comment: I forgot to tell onething .The error used display as soon as it uploads theme and before activating the theme.The themes used able to work at that time even though they show error . I am getting an error "The active theme is broken. Reverting to the default theme." when uploading but it is actually working well when I click on activate again .Now after getting your reply I have tried deleting the previous ones and uploading them via file manager and got no errors. By the way I am trying this on two installations which are on different servers and hosting companies as well .

Comment: OK, if the themes were already present on the server when you tried to upload them, *that's* what was causing the error.  The uploader isn't designed to overwrite existing themes ... though I've heard that's a planned feature for the future ...

Comment: Sorry for not making clear .There were not already on the server .I am not trying to replace existing ones.I am trying to tell you that the error exists but the theme is works well .

Comment: So do you get the error while uploading the themes (as your question states) or after the theme are uploaded?

Comment: Sorry for not making clear by myself .This is the screen shot of error http://imgur.com/xZVvT.jpg

Comment: OK, the issue there was that the stylesheet (`spacegloss-free/style.css`) didn't get transferred for some reason ... potentially an issue with your server setup and *not* with WordPress itself.  When WordPress tried to unpack the theme, it stumbled over the missing stylesheet which it expected to exist.  Check your folder and see if this file is there ... WordPress requires this specific file to load information about the theme.